# Reading data from database into form form for editing

Tags: php, sql

In my web application, I'm reading data from database into a form so that I can edit a record. The data is coming with forward slashes into the form which is undesirable. Instead of a name being put in the form as "Francis" it is put as "Francis/". May someone that has experienced this please help.

Comment: [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) would help.

Comment: can you write your code here? explain

Comment: Thank you. rtrim has done the job.

Comment: @mario add that as an answer so

Comment: please share your code here..

Comment: I actually discovered that I wasn't rtrim that really helped. But it worked the way I wanted because I changed the following: echo'<input name="fname" value="'.$fname.'"/>' to echo'<input name="fname" value="'.$fname.'">'. I removed the forward slash that closes the input element. I hope this will not affect how my codes runs in other browsers.